# Target the first label using CSS

Tags: css

I'm styling a portal where I cannot change any HTML but CSS and came across the following bit of code and I want to target the first label(Your Name).

```
<form class="no-tables" name="" action="" method="post">
    <div>
        <input type="hidden" name="" value="1">
        <label>Your Name</label>
        <label>Your Age</label>
    </div>
</form>
```

I tried chevron and first-child selectors but none seem to work.

Comment: [This](https://jsfiddle.net/yL3thtr9/) is not CSS3 and maybe you can use it. It would still require the label and input to appear as pairs. So maybe CSS3 is your best bet.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using `first-of-type`:

```css
/* CSS3 */
form.no-tables > div > label:first-of-type {
  background: red;
}

/* or with CSS2 */
form.no-tables > div > input + label {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<form class="no-tables" name="" action="" method="post">
  <div>
    <input type="hidden" name="" value="1">
    <label>Your Name</label>
    <label>Your Age</label>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks Scott. Is there a solution with CSS 2 at all?

Comment: @fcaldern - Thanks, but I cannot use input + as some other forms don't have that control unfortunately.

Comment: Ah, in that case, I think you're stuck with CSS3, unless you can select it with JS.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by using `input + label` for CSS2 only.

*edit* So **fcalderan** mentioned this already.

```css
input + label {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<form class="no-tables" name="" action="" method="post">
    <div>
        <input type="hidden" name="" value="1">
        <label>Your Name</label>
        <label>Your Age</label>
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks, everyone! Looks like I'm going to have to resort to using CSS 3.